# Omit method execution of stubbed object

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I have a code listed below inside one of my method which I would like to test:

```
using (var obj1 = provider.GetObj1Instance())
{
    /*  Do some stuff  */
    obj1.DoAction();
}
```

provider is an object which I mocked:

```
provider = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IProvider>();
```

but method GetObj1Instance() returns concrete-typed object. Right now after mocking I get NullRefrenceException, because method GetObj1Instance() from mocked provider returns null.

Then I stubbed obj1:

```
var stubbedObj1 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<Obj1>();
provider.Stub(o => o.GetObj1Instance()).Return(stubbedObj1);
```

but it's not sufficient, because inside obj1.DoAction(); there is reference to private variable which throws NullReferenceException

During test execution, I would like to not execute obj1.DoAction() or just to register that it was invoked. How to achieve that?

This line below doesn't prevent DoAction method from original execution.

```
stubbedObj1.Stub(u => u.DoAction()).Do(new Action(() => { }));
```

Comment: Is the `DoAction` method `virtual`? Or can you make it `virtual`?

Comment: It's not and I can't make it, because it comes from external library

Comment: Do you have control over `IProvider`? Can you make it return some `IObject1` instead of `Obj1`? You can then create an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that adapts `Obj1` to `IObject1`.

Comment: I don't have control over it and I can't change it